# imagejpeg shows a blank image for creating captcha

Tags: php, html, header, captcha

I tried 3 different codes to create a captcha for my php project,but they all showed gibberish html instead of actually executing it.
I tried both imagepng and imagejpeg and even added the header attribute,but instead of working,it shows nothing but a blank image in the middle of the browser page.I looked up all stack overflow questions for this,but none seems to work for me.

When I remove the header attribute it writes gibberish but when I remove it it shows me a blank image.Is there anyone that can help me?

Here's the last code I coded:

```
<?php
session_Start();

$length = rand(0,56);
$shuffle=str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
$text = substr($shuffle,$length,6);
$_SESSION["captcha"] = $text;

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(18,22);
imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);

$fontSize = 24;
$rotate = 13;
$xRotate = 50;
$yRotate = 70;
$font =  getcwd()."\\public\\fonts\\arial.ttf";
$color = imagecolorallocate($im,255,0,255);

imagettftext($im,$fontSize,$rotate,$xRotate,$yRotate,$color,$font,$text);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);

?>
```

Comment: Look for image handling examples on php.net. Try removing the `?>` as you dont want to output whitespace characters accidentally. Try moving up the `header` function to the beginning of your script. Review all parameters of the image functions using the docs.

Comment: I tried them all,but didn't work.I remember my professor told us one of these functions doesn't work on all php versions.My php version is 5.6.40.It's supposed to work according to php.net.I even tried copying a GeeksFroGeeks code into my project but it didn't work either.

Comment: I think I understood my mistake